# BCC LD86 file has bad magic number

Tags: bcc-compiler

I wanted to write a simple hello world program in DOSBox, so I downloaded Bruce's C Compiler from [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.2/repos/pkg-html/bcc.html). And wrote this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

I ran bcc like this: `bcc -o hello hello.c`, but I get this error every time:

```
C:\BCC\DEVEL\BCC\BIN\LD86.EXE: HELLO.C has bad magic number
```

I don't know why this is happening, if anyone can tell me please do.

Comment: FYI, this is the sort of question that ends up on Retro SE. If you don't get any help here you can check there. https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jdv Thanks, will post the question there if nobody helps here.